# Improve performance of Select stmt from table with lots of records

Tags: sql, sqlite

How to improve performance of the select query which retrieve 500 items from table with 100000 rows and with ordering by any column.

At the moment I'm using the following query:

```
select * 
from Table1 
order by Column10 desc, Id asc 
limit :rowsOnPage offset :offset
```

Is there better way?

Comment: Do you have indexes on `Column10` and `Id`?

Comment: Seems indexing is not very usable here because result can be order by **any** column. If I will create index for each column I think it can degrade DB performance

Comment: indices degrade performance on `DELETE\INSERT\UPDATE`, Lack of indices degrade performance on `SELECT`. It's a trade off.

Comment: @Ghost, any other ways to increase the speed? Maybe some views or special tables for cached items?

Comment: @Alex I'm not really a sqlite guy, I'm fairly sure this is not sql-server even though it's tagged as such. There's some caching you could do, but I don't know how to do it sqlite wise, or even how possible that is.

Comment: mixing asc and desc in the order clause will most likely mean even if there is an index the db can't use it. There isn't a magic pill - queries are made faster with indexes - create usable indexes (which may mean modifying your query or table structure)